# Broadcast messages don't appear on gnome-terminal, but appear on xterm

Tags: terminal, broadcast

I'm curious about the behavior of broadcast messages by

```
$ sudo wall myfile
```

the message from `myfile` appears on all `/dev/ttyN` devices (the ones to which I can switch by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>fN</kbd>), it also appears on the `xterm` windows I have opened, but it doesn't appear on `gnome-terminal` (actually I use Linux Mint with MATE, so it's `mate-terminal`, but it is fork of `gnome-terminal`).

There's also interesting note if I run `tmux` in the `xterm`: I expected that the message would appear on all terminal sessions that are running in `tmux` (on all windows, and in each pane of each window), but actually the message appears just at current cursor position in the `xterm` window.

If I check current controlling terminal by calling `tty`, it reports different terminals for different windows in tmux: say, I have `/dev/pts/11` in one tmux window and `/dev/pts/12` in another one. But, broadcast message appears just once for each `xterm` window, not for each terminal session opened in `tmux`.

It seems to me that terminal emulator, when allocating pseudo-terminal, needs, like, "registering" it somewhere to make it able to receive broadcast messages, and so, `xterm` does it, but `mate-terminal` and `tmux` does not. But it sounds weird since pseudo-terminal is allocated by the kernel, so, it should be "registered" automatically everywhere it needs to be.

I'd be glad if someone explain how does it work and why the behavior is that (seemingly weird).

Comment: No reproducible.

Comment: @Braiam, even with tmux? That is, if you run tmux session with several windows and/or panes, your broadcast message appears in each window/pane?

Comment: I have the same problem, however here it works with `gnome-terminal`, but not with `urxvt`.

Comment: does gnome-terminal turn off `mesg` ?

Comment: `mesg "is y"` both on `gnome-terminal` and `urxvt` here.

Comment: `tmux` solves the problem with `gnome-terminal`. Thank you all for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

The terminals listed hints that the behavior is seen with Linux: The clues are in the manual page for [`wall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html) ([Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19109-01/tsolaris8/817-0880/6mglau879/index.html) for instance is different):

> `wall` displays a message, or the contents of a file, or otherwise its
>   standard input, on the terminals of all currently *logged in users*.
>
> Some sessions, such as `wdm`, that have in the beginning of [*utmp(5)*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/utmp.5.html)
>   `ut_type` data a ':' character will not get the message from `wall`.
>   This is done to avoid write errors.

That is, `wall` uses the utmp data, looks for terminals in use (i.e., logged-in users), and writes to the associated *device*.  Each line in the output of `w` shows a (possible) terminal, recorded by the terminal in the utmp file.  For instance, I am ssh'd into a server and running screen while at the same time I logged into a console.  Just for completeness, I ran xterm using the `-ls` (login-shell) option.  Here is the output of `w`:

```
$ w
 19:53:15 up  4:08,  5 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.05
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
tom      tty2                      19:48    5:11   0.04s  0.02s -tcsh
tom      pts/0    michener:S.0     15:51   13:18   0.35s  0.24s ssh -X thomas@b
tom      pts/2    michener:S.1     16:34    2.00s  0.14s  0.00s sh -c w
tom      pts/4    michener:S.3     15:52    3:59m  0.12s  0.00s /bin/sh /users/
tom      pts/3    localhost:10.0   19:53    7.00s  0.03s  0.03s -tcsh
```

and running `wall` writes to each of those `TTY` devices.

However, if the terminal does *not* write to the utmp file, it will not be listed — and `wall` will ignore it.

Now, some programs may have the feature compiled-in, but lack privileges to change it.  That is why some programs are run with `setgid` to the "utmp" group.  Other programs (such as xterm — or gnome-terminal) may use an external program that updates utmp on their behalf.

With gnome-terminal, the feature has been deprecated due to the mindset of the gnome developers that (a) users run on a local machine, where **`gdm`** handles login, and (b) consequently there's no distinction worth bothering about between login shells and non-login shells.  That makes for some interesting bug reports:

- [[Solved, deprecated upstream] who -m and w don't show pty logins](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203764) (Arch)
- [Bug 747046: cleanup pty.c](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046) (Gnome)
- [Bug 159363: gnome-pty-helper doesn't clean up gnome-terminals' utmp/wtmp entries when killed](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?format=multiple&id=159363) (Red Hat)
- [Bug 71368: Summary:     gnome-terminal "update utmp/wtmp" option doesn't work when not using gdm](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=71368) (Red Hat)

Answer (score 1):

On `urxvt`, you have to issue

```
chown root.utmp /usr/bin/urxvt
chmod g+s /usr/bin/urxvt
```

Then it starts working.

I don't understand why, just copied (and tested) from http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.rxvt-unicode.general/1484.