# How do I send a notification to all active shells, like shutdown does?

Tags: terminal, notifications, broadcast

You know, I was just there, doing my things, when suddenly a terrible **Broadcast message** appeared!

```
fiatjaf@mises ~> sl
fiatjaf@mises ~> ls dotfiles/
urxvt
vim/
vimrc
fiatjaf@mises ~> cowsay good morning
 ______________
< good morning >
 --------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
fiatjaf@mises ~> 
fiatjaf@mises ~> 
Broadcast message from root@mises
    (/dev/pts/3) at 11:12 ...

The system is going down for maintenance NOW!
```

How can trigger a message like this from my own programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`man wall` will give you what you need.

You execute `wall` with either a filename, or you pipe content to it.

For example, either,

`wall file.name` to broadcast the content of the file `file.name` or

`echo "Dive\!" | wall` to send the message Dive!

Update: As Stephen points out in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277823/8357), later versions of `wall` can send messages by simply typing,

`wall message text here`

and in fact, there are additional restrictions on non-root users sending the contents of files by specifying only the file name.

Comment: It works! Thank you. But why it doesn't work on `urxvt`, only on `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150697/broadcast-messages-dont-appear-on-gnome-terminal-but-appear-on-xterm

Comment: what's the output of `mesg`? "mesg n" would inhibit a `wall` (in [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall), anyway)

Comment: I think it's actually a known issue with `urxvt`, a quick search shows several queries asking why `wall`'s don't arrive.

Answer (score 4):

You simply use [`wall`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wall.1.html); running it as `root` will ensure every terminal displays the message.

```
wall Your attention please\!
```

Older versions of `wall` only accept a file name on their command-line, or a message piped in:

```
echo Your attention please\! | wall
```

Comment: Thank you, but it isn't working like this, it is asking for a file.

Comment: `wall` displays either the contents of a file (when run as `wall file`) or it's standard input (so run as `echo hello | wall`).  `wall <text>` doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Yes it does, perhaps only in recent versions `bsdutils` or `util-linux` though.