# Why can't I send messages with the wall command?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, write

I'm trying to send messages with either wall or write.  To test this, I opened two gnome-terminal windows.  Then entered the following in one window:

```
me@host>>wall
message to everyone


<ctrl> + d
```

When I finished the message I sent an <s>interrupt signal</s> EOF character with  (ctrl-d).  Instead of sending the message, the terminal beeped at me as if I entered invalid input.  I get similar behavior with write.  Can someone help me with what is wrong?

Edit: Here is the permissions info:

```
me@host>>ls -l $(type -p wall)
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 27368 May 26 18:31 /usr/bin/wall
```

Comment: Ctrl/D isn't Interrupt, it's End Of File (EOF). Ctrl/C is interrupt.

Comment: Output of `ls -l $(type -p wall)` added to your question, please. (It should be setgid tty)

Comment: @roaima -rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 27368 May 26 18:31 /usr/bin/wall

Comment: So to be clear, you get a beep and do not see the message, right?  Because I seem to recall `wall` causing a terminal beep for me before when I received a message

Comment: Tip: using `tmux` inside wall-problematic session resolves the situation.

Answer (score 3):

Both `wall` and `write` on Debian (and Ubuntu) use setgid (*set-group-id*) privilege to the **`tty`** group to allow those programs to write into the terminals of other users.

However, it is common for administrators of shared computer systems to disable this feature.  You can see the permissions by doing

```
ls -lL /usr/bin/write /usr/bin/wall
```

and on a normal system would see this (dates do not matter):

```
$ ls -lL /usr/bin/write /usr/bin/wall
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 23056 Dec 11  2012 /usr/bin/wall
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root tty 14624 Jun 11  2012 /usr/bin/write
```

The **`s`** in the first field **`-rwxr-sr-x`** is the setgid bit, and the fourth field is the group **`tty`**.  You need both (or an equivalent group) to make the feature work.

Besides permissions, there is another aspect which you will run into using gnome-terminal: `wall` and `write` send their messages to **logged-in users**.  They get that information from the utmp data file, which gnome-terminal does not support.

Further reading:

- [Broadcast messages don't appear on gnome-terminal, but appear on xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150697/broadcast-messages-dont-appear-on-gnome-terminal-but-appear-on-xterm/283543#283543)
- [Is gnome terminal is a type of non login shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307990/is-gnome-terminal-is-a-type-of-non-login-shell/308000#308000)
- [source-code for **`write`**](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/term-utils/write.c#n127)
- [source-code for **`wall`**](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/term-utils/wall.c#n162)
- [Bug 71368 - gnome-terminal "update utmp/wtmp" option doesn't work when not using gdm](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=71368)
- [Bug 747046 - cleanup pty.c](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046)

Comment: I can see this answers the question as posed - but can it be boiled down to: say, if you're using Ubuntu 20.04 where the default terminal is `gnome-terminal`, you simply cannot use `wall` as intended at all? Or are there settings that can be changed, so `wall` works on those systems too?

Comment: See bug #71368 - looks like the answer is "no"