# WSL2 Ubuntu - wall command

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wall

I'm trying to setup a simple script to run on a cron job that runs in the background and notifies any open terminals of the outcome using the `wall` command. However when testing, I don't get any output at all. I'm using WSL Ubuntu and zsh via the Terminal app from Microsoft.

Running `tty` and `w` returns the below, while `who` returns nothing at all.

```
 hardya@GBH-HARDYA1  ~  tty
/dev/pts/4
 hardya@GBH-HARDYA1  ~  w
 09:16:01 up 3 days,  4:30,  0 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably related to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1365696/1086345). I'm pretty sure that the owner of that answer will provide you an explanation here! :)

Comment: Thanks @EdgarMagallon, I'd not found that particular one. So you're saying IF `wall` using the same behind the scenes info as `who`, it might be that it's fundamentally incompatible with WSL at the moment

Comment: Yeah, and as I said you have an answer now by that user! I do know nothing about WSL/Windows so I was not able to provide a full explanation and solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@EdgarMagallon is correct on two counts in the comments:

- This *is* related to the `who` command issue mentioned on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1365678/1165986)
- The owner of that answer (me) will ... ;-)

Ok, so yes, the `wall` command does appear to use the same mechanism as `who` for determining the logged-in users and their terminals.

So to get it to work under WSL2:

- You'll need a recent release of WSL that reports 0.67.6 or higher (preferably 1.0.3 or higher) in `wsl --version`.  If it returns `invalid command`, make sure that your Windows is fully updated, then install the new [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://aka.ms/wslstorepage) from the Microsoft Store.
- Enable Systemd as noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379567/1165986)
- After restarting WSL and confirming that Systemd is enabled, run `su - $USER` to force a "login" of your user.
- Then, in another terminal, you can run:

  ```
  sudo wall Wallaby # Or a real message
  ```

  And it should display in the logged-in terminal.  Keep in mind that `sudo` is required on many distributions.  It used to be that [`wall` was `setguid` on Ubuntu and Debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/313558/432493), but that doesn't appear to be the case any longer.
- `w` and `who` should also show your logged-in user.

Of course, this doesn't necessarily help you achieve your desired script, since WSL doesn't *force* logins.  Some possibilities for that:

- Force a `su - $USER` login in shells where you want to receive the notifications.
- Write a Zsh prompt function to monitor a file (or perhaps fifo?) and update the prompt with the "completion" information (until cleared).  Note that I find this easier in Fish, but I feel certain it would be possible in Zsh (or even Bash) as well.
- Run `tmux` in your terminal(s) and use `tmux display-message` to notify of the competion.