# Seeing user two times

Tags: login, session, who, w

Consider I have created a user '`test`' during Installation which I use to login to my system. My root user is '`root`'. I further open two terminal sessions for each of the users respectively. Now the problem is when I type the '`w`', '`who`' or even the '`finger`' command (*in my root terminal session*) to list all users logged in, I see the '`test`' user coming in two times (*with different TTYs*), which should have actually been '`test`' & '`root`'. Even If I create a new user '`test1`', I still see my original username name '`test`' is being the output of `w`, `who`, `finger` commands for users currently logged in.
Something like this:
[image: RHEL7 Terminal]
Why so?

PS.: Using `RHEL7`

Comment: "_I further open two terminal sessions for each of the users respectively_" how do you do this?

Comment: New terminal window, I then use "su - username" to log in to the other user @roaima

Comment: BTW, it's good practice to create a user account for your daily work (maybe `alistair`), give it `sudo` rights be editing `sudoers`, and never login as `root` at all, unless in emergencies. (yes, you didn't ask this, but I've seen many people use root as their main account, which isn't a good idea).

Comment: `w` or `who` don't print any interesting or reliable info. Do **not** rely on them. Longer rant [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484651/why-is-top-command-showing-users-that-the-who-command-is-not#comment889771_484651)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> New terminal window, I then use `su - username` to log in to the other user

This is your error of thinking.  *You are **not** logging in.*

`su` does not create a login session.  It is not a login mechanism. It "switches user" to run a program under the aegis of a different user account, adding privileges (that account's privileges) to the totality of privileges available to the user of the *existing login session* that it is run in.

The login database, reported by those various commands, lists login sessions.  Adding privileges in an *existing* session does not change it, naturally.

(Some GUI terminal emulators, but not all, add login database entries for each emulated terminal that they provide.  Yours is, but that is *not* `su` doing it.  The entry is added long before you get around to running a `su` command in a shell using that terminal.)

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2014). *[Don't abuse su for dropping user privileges](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dont-abuse-su-for-dropping-privileges.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441817/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/283543/5132

Answer (score 2):

Have you previously killed any sessions of user `test` using `kill -9`?

Depending on operating system and the way it handles updates to the `utmp`/`wtmp` files, killing a user session with `kill -9` may cause its session record in the `utmp` file to be left in a "session is active" state.

When a new session using the same (pseudo)TTY device is initialized, the code that writes the `utmp` entry sees that the slot for that TTY device is already used by an active entry, and uses the next free slot.

Then, commands like `w`, `who` or `finger` have a sensible expectation that only one user at a time can be using a TTY device, so once they find one entry for a particular TTY device, they won't look for any others... and so they display the wrong, stale entry instead of the one that is actually current.

The `utmpdump` command can be used to dump the binary `utmp` file into text format, for seeing if this kind of utmp corruption has happened. Then you can edit the text version to remove the stale entries, and use `utmpdump -r` to reconstruct a new binary `utmp` file with the corrupted entries removed.

Or, if you can have all the users log out for a moment, just have everyone else log out, truncate the utmp file to zero size, logout and log back in.

```
# echo "Everyone logout now, please" | wall
# > /var/run/utmp
# <logout>
```

And in the future, please use `kill -HUP` to end shell sessions instead of `kill -9` or `kill -KILL` to avoid this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

> I further open two terminal sessions for each of the users respectively

And then in a comment you clarified that after opening a new terminal window

> I then use "su - username" to log in to the other user

Opening the terminal window generates the entry in `utmp`. The `su` command does not. So every window you open will be registered to your original user account that's logged in.